# Location Manager delegate call to update TableView issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, cllocationmanager

I have a `tableView` that is populated with a `fetchedResultsController`. Everything works fine. As it stands, the `tableView` loads data from the `managedObjectContext` as desired. The problem is it's too much data, so I've created a `CLLocationManager` class with a protocol that notifies the `tableView` when it's got a location and the tableView controller adds a predicate onto the `fetchedResultsController` to pare down the number of possibilities.

The problem I've encountered is on the **initial load** of the app. It seems as though the `LocationManager` delegate is getting called before the `tableView` is done loading.

I keep getting this error on the initial launch, but **not on subsequent launches**:

> [error] error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo (null)
>
> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo (null)

```
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationManagerDelegate: class {
  func updateTableView()
}

class LocationManager: NSObject {
  static let sharedInstance = LocationManager()
  public var currentLocation: CLLocation? {
    get {
      return locationManager.location
    }
  }
  private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  private override init() {
    super.init()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    self.getCurrentLocation()
  }
  public weak var delegate: LocationManagerDelegate?

  public func updateLocation() {
    getCurrentLocation()
  }

  private func getCurrentLocation() {
    // Also tried without the DispatchQueue
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    // DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync {
      self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
      self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
  }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    delegate?.updateTableView()
    // still crashes
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
     self.delegate?.updateTableView()
     }
  }
}
```

I had been starting up the `locationManager` in `AppDelegate.swift` in an effort to speed load time.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      LocationManager.sharedInstance.updateLocation()
      return true
  }
```

Thinking that was the culprit, I moved it to the end of `viewDidLoad` without success. The app loads fine and `locationManager`'s delegate after the initial launch, but I can't get around the error in the initial launch.

Here is my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` implementation:

```
// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods
extension MyViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
  func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
  }

  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch (type) {
    case .insert:
      if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
      }
      break;
    case .delete:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
      }
      break;
    case .update:
      if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        configureCell(cell, at: indexPath)
      }
      break;
    case .move:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
      }

      if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    print("controller didChange sectionInfo")
  }
}

extension MyViewController: LocationManagerDelegate {
  func updateTableView() {
    filterBasedOnDistance(miles: Double(slider.value))
  }
}
```

Here are the methods that are called by `updateTableView()`:

```
  private func degreeRangeInMiles(degrees: Double, miles: Double) -> Range<Double> {
    let metersPerDegree: Double = 111_000
    let degreesInMeters = degrees * metersPerDegree

    let metersPerMileDouble = 1_609.344
    let milesDifferential = miles * metersPerMileDouble

    let upperBound = (degreesInMeters + milesDifferential) / metersPerDegree
    let lowerBound = (degreesInMeters - milesDifferential) / metersPerDegree

    return Range(lowerBound..<upperBound)
  }

  func filterBasedOnDistance(miles: Double) {
    guard locationManager.currentLocation != nil else { return }

    let latitude = locationManager.currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = locationManager.currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude

    let latitudeRange = degreeRangeInMiles(degrees: latitude!, miles: miles)
    let longitudeRange = degreeRangeInMiles(degrees: longitude!, miles: miles)

    let distancePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude BETWEEN { \(latitudeRange.lowerBound),\(latitudeRange.upperBound) } AND longitude BETWEEN {\(longitudeRange.lowerBound),\(longitudeRange.upperBound)}")

    fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = distancePredicate

    do {
      try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

I'm trying to figure out where my mistake lies and how do I fix it? Thank you for reading!

**Update**

I tried adding a public-facing get-only property on my `LocationManager` class to determine the device's authorization status:

```
  public var locationServicesAuthorized: Bool {
    get {
      return CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    }
  }
```

And I updated my delegate method call as follows:

```
extension MyViewController: LocationManagerDelegate {
  func updateTableView() {
    guard locationManager.locationServicesAuthorized else { return }
    filterBasedOnDistance(miles: Double(slider.value))
  }
}
```

Same result. I get the error that there's an invalid number of sections, even though I've got `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` implemented.

Comment: Your didChange sectionInfo method needs to add/delete sections in response to .insert and .delete change type.

Comment: @pbasdf I see what you're talking about. I don't know what to put in there.

Comment: Sorry - I’ve been looking for boilerplate code in Swift, but can only find [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate) which is Objective C.  Not too difficult to translate though.  Essentially you just need to check the change type and call tableView insertSections or deleteSections methods accordingly.

Comment: @pbasdf If you want to copy my answer, I'll accept yours so you get the 25 points.

Comment: Thanks, but no worries - you did the leg work, I just pointed the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At **pbasdf's** suggestion, I implemented `didChange sectionInfo` NSFetchedResultsController delegate method. [Apple's boilerplate on their site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate) is in Objective-C, but here's the translated Swift version:

```
  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case .insert:
      tableView.insertSections([sectionIndex], with: .fade)
      break
    case .delete:
      tableView.deleteSections([sectionIndex], with: .fade)
    default:
      break
    }
  }
```